# Open modal based on url with #

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have two modals I want to show when right fragment is in the URL, so `domain.com#steg2` loads modal #steg2 and `domain.com#steg3` loads modal #steg3.

My script:

```
$(function() {
    if (window.location.hash.indexOf("steg2") !== -1) {
        $("#steg2").modal();
    }
    if (window.location.hash.indexOf("steg3") !== -1) {
        $("#steg3").modal();
    }
});
```

This is how my modals are buildt:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="steg2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">


<div class="modal fade" id="steg3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Both modals are on same page/URL. What am i doing wrong? Site is using bootstrap 3 and jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

After some trials I found this code to do the work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var target = document.location.hash.replace("#", "");
if (target.length) {
if(target=="steg1"){
  $('#steg1').modal('show');
}
else if(target=="steg2"){
  $('#steg2').modal('show');
}
else if(target=="steg3"){
  $('#steg3').modal('show');
}
}
else{    
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
function hashModal () {
    var stegs = ['steg2','steg3'],
        hash = window.location.hash,
        stegAt = stegs.indexOf(hash.replace('#','');
    if (stegAt > -1) {
        $(hash + '.modal').modal();
    }
}

$(document).on('ready hashchange', hashModal);
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
  - [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location).
- jQuery:

  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Thanks, I tried you suggestion, but no modal show's when i enter domain.com#steg2. Any ideas on what i might do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First get the hash from the url with `window.location.hash`. That value will have a # prepended to it. Then you can use it directly as a jquery selector.

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
    if(hash != '') {
          $(hash).modal();
    }
```